# What is causing the rest of the frames to go dark?

Tags: rendering

Frame 1 to 63 are fine but frame 64 to 600 are significantly darker. How do I fix this problem and what could have caused it?

Frame 1:

[image]

Frame 64:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Hard to say, maybe share your file, only keep several objects to make the file lighter